# async-await not setting state with axios

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need to figure out why if I use `async-await` in the handleDelete method the setState does not call.

**Client Delete handler:**

This does work, but not with async await like I would want it too.

```
  handleDelete = studentId => {
    try {
      axios.delete(`/students/${studentId}`)
      this.setState(prevState => ({
        students: prevState.students.filter(
          student => student._id !== studentId
        ),
      }))
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(`Error: ${e}`)
    }
  }
```

**Backend Function:**

This is the function that is responsible to delete a user from the document.

```
exports.deleteStudent = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    await Student.findByIdAndRemove(req.params.studentId)
    return res.status(204)
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(`Error: ${e}`)
  }
}
```

Comment: Can we see your attempt at using it in `handleDelete`?

Comment: @Li357 yes, my handle delete works fine. It even deletes when I have async in front of studentId and await in front of axios. However; it does not run this.setState. Even when I console.log(this.state) in the setState callback I don't see anything.

Comment: It could be better if you use handleDelete as an async function, but it should work as it is. What about a console.log() after axios.delete? Does it work?

Comment: Sure. Without async await for the handleDelete I do see the state. It does without a refresh from the state and db. With the async await I do not see anything returned but it does get deleted. I need to refresh to see. Nothing is returned from this.state.

Comment: It's because of both actions (`axios` & `setState`) are async

Comment: @JosephChambers, a simple console.log works after axios.delete but setState does not work if you use async-await? What do you get if you use await on axios.delete, set it to a variable and console.log it? `const result = await axios.delete(....); console.log( result );`